# Locker smartcontract in solidity withdraw function error

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

I am developing a locker smart contract where a user can send erc20 tokens and set the time for a locking period. For the withdraw function I want to implement:

1. the locking time should passed
2. the address( wallet) lock the token can only withdraw

I am having difficulty to build the logic for withdraw function.

Here is the code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract lock  {
    address public owner;
    
   struct Lock{
       address token;
       uint amount;
       uint endtime;

    }

    constructor() {
     owner= msg.sender;
     
    }

    mapping(address => Lock) public tokenLock;

    function locker( address _token, uint256 _amount, uint _time) public{
        
        tokenLock[msg.sender]= Lock(_token, _amount, _time);
        IERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),_amount);
    }
    
    function chkBalance(address _token) public view returns (uint){
        return  IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

   
    /** HERE **/
    function claim(address _token) public {
        require(_time >block.timestamp);
 
    }
    /** END-HERE **/
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
function claim() public {
    // Get the Lock for the requester
    Lock storage lock = tokenLock[msg.sender];

    // Check timestamp
    require(lock.endtime >= block.timestamp);

    // Transfer locked tokens
    IERC20(lock.token).transfer(msg.sender, lock.amount);
}
```

Comment: how to implement this logic, *the address( wallet) lock the token can only withdraw

Comment: @learner The logic is implicit in the use of `msg.sender` as index to store the Lock. An address can only withdraw from its own lock. I haven't done any error check, you shouldn't use this code for production. The error checks are left as exercise.